# Regex Validation doesn't work under a update panel

Tags: asp.net

I have to validate two textboxes, all inside an update panel. The code for the regex is fine as its one I am using in another textbox in the project, but this one has the unique case that its under an update panel. The problem is that the Regex doesn't want to work inside the update panel and it HAS to work inside since data is filled to these textboxes dynamically and without having to do constant postbacks. This is the ASP code for one...

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server"
      ControlToValidate="txtMoney" Display="Dynamic" 
      ErrorMessage="Verifyb quantity" ForeColor="Red" Height="6px" 
      ValidationExpression="^\$?([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(.[0-9][0-9])?$" 
      Width="500px"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The code works as I am using that exact one (with of course the `ControltoValidate` correctly changed) but it gives me no validation on text or when a button is pressed. I am using VS2012 and VB.NET. I see some problems regarding this but I've seen no solid fix so far.

Comment: Some additional work might require check if this helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398929(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Well what do you know..... Will check into that. Thanks Yuriy